# Making a Panel having a Child with "Top" or "Fill" Docking show scroll bars after child element's MinimumSize

Tags: c#, winforms, scrollbar, panel

**Issue:**

I am creating a dynamic table that needs to have various custom controls supplied to me from another independent code.
(Already tried DevExpress solutions)

I have a Parent Panel. The panel contains child Panel(s). Child Panels need to have a Dock of "Top" / "Fill". Using anchor is not a solution for my scenario.

```
// childElements required inside the parent
childElements[i].Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

However when I use Dock "Top" / "Fill", the Parent Panel Ignores MinimumSize attribute of Child elements and fails to display ScrollBars.

**What is Required**

The Parent Panel must have Child elements with Dock = Fill / Top

The Parent Panel must show vertical scroll bars if its size is inadequate to display Child element(s)

**Related questions and why they were inadequate:**

1. [Making control docking and scrollbars play nicely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674003/making-control-docking-and-scrollbars-play-nicely?rq=1)

Here the issue has been accepted as "inevitable"

2. [Scrollbar doesn't appear in parent control if the child is docked to the edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24578216/scrollbar-doesnt-appear-in-parent-control-if-the-child-is-docked-to-the-edge)

Has a nice drawing of same issue.
Again the accepted answer says the issue is by design and has no solution.

**Screen Captures of desired behavior:**

Fill behavior with Parent expanded

[Parent Expanded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIGdQ.png)

Scrolling behavior with Parent made smaller

[Parent Contracted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CP4G.png)

**Solution:**

I made the Child element Dock = Fill/Top as required.
At the end of element creation I added a Panel to the parent without any Dock and with the Size equal to required min size of the Child. 
(sum of min size, for multiple child elements)

```
// sumOfChildMinimumHeight = Sum the child.MinimumSize.Height of Child elements
Panel verticalSizeLimiter = new Panel();
verticalSizeLimiter.Location = new Point(0, 0);
verticalSizeLimiter.Size = new Size(1, sumOfChildMinimumHeight);

parentPanel.Controls.Add(verticalLimiter);
```

This element is hidden due to Dock properties of Child elements.
This made the Parent show vertical scroll bars after the MinimumSize and I could use Dock = "Top"/"Fill" on Child elements.

NOTE: Even if the MinimumSize attribute is not read from the Child elements, this solves my requirement mentioned in **"What is Required"** i.e. Dock = Fill and Scroll after MinimumSize at the same time.

I posted this as answer to [Scrollbar doesn't appear in parent control if the child is docked to the edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24578216/scrollbar-doesnt-appear-in-parent-control-if-the-child-is-docked-to-the-edge) which was however deleted as "This does not really answer the question"

NOTE: Adding solution to answer as my previous answer to this on related post got me banned from Answering

Comment: So you are asking a question without needing an answer?

Comment: @ElGavilan Please read above post that describes the actual issue which I was searching. The thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24578216/scrollbar-doesnt-appear-in-parent-control-if-the-child-is-docked-to-the-edge is asking a solution for the same issue, but describing from a coding point of view rather than a behavior point of view. And the solution in my post solves this. I made a new thread as I cannot comment on existing threads and cannot answer questions since your review of my answer

Comment: But it looked like you deleted it yourself.  A couple of users flagged it as not an answer.  At first read, it looked more like a question than an answer, especially since you started your post with "Same Issue".

Comment: @LarsTech Why will I delete it, it solves the problem. The previous OP did not explain what he was doing. I explained what I was doing. Looking for my issue I found that his post was actually the same issue. The child Panel kept its size but Parent refused to show scroll bars. When I see the post it says deleted by "ElGavilan". So  suppose that is what it is. I said "Same Issue" and solution right ? So it is an answer.